# добавить исходники в cmake

Tags: cmake

здравствуйте, есть большой проект с Cmake... я добавляю пару строк в один из файлов, например

```
C a; 
a.foo();
```

создаю папку directory, кладу туда новые исходники, реализующие этот класс и его функционал, например class_c.cpp. Чтобы теперь собрать проект без ошибок, как эти исходники добавить в cmake?

я так понимаю, в папке directory создаем CMakeLists.txt и туда добавляем

```
set(SOURCES class_c.cpp)
```

будет ли этого достаточно?

Answer (score 2):

Нет, это просто создание переменной. Чтобы добавить исходники в какую-то цель (target), нужно вставить значение этой переменной (или просто сами сорцы) в один из вызовов `add_executable()`/`add_library()`.